# In "8 mile" what does this lyric mean?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, 8-mile

In the ultimate rap battle between the protagonist Rabbit and Papa Doc, Rabbit says

> 1, 2, 3, and to the 4
>   One Pac, two Pac, three Pac, four
>   Four Pac, three Pac, two Pac, one
>   You're Pac, he's Pac, no Pac, none

What on earth is this about? What's more, Rabbit points at members of Papa Doc's entourage while saying this and in fact indicated that "none" is in reference to himself. I've seen claims that it refers to the protagonist considering the members of The Free World as poor imitations of Tupac (which seems a bit of a stretch), and also the claim that it is a criticism of Papa Doc's need to surround himself with lackeys (though Rabbit also has followers with him, so this undermines this theory somewhat).

Four lines near the start of the song give it quite a lot of emphasis, particularly with the counting up, and back down. It also elicits quite a response from the audience, so clearly they consider it to be a significant attack on Papa Doc, but what does it mean?  Why does the crowd react the way they do?

Comment: @Paulie_D hmm... to me it seems that the interpretation of the lyrics is important o understanding what's going on in this scene.  so I personally think this is on-topic for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As explained on genius.com](https://genius.com/Eminem-8-mile-b-rabbit-vs-papa-doc-lyrics):

> Rabbit points at a different member of Doc’s crew (Free World) each
>   time he says a number. This implies that they are all trying to
>   emulate 2Pac, ripping off his sound and look.

Comment: This could be just poor screen writing but Doc is "no Pac" and Rabbit is "none" Pac? And the elaborate counting hmm..

Comment: @Stumbler maybe he wanted to say that none of them, including him could ever match or be close to 2pac